# Is my tree OK? (Bubbly effect on stem of Rainbow Eucalyptus)

Tags: trees, diseases, pests

We have a ~1 year old [Rainbow Eucalyptus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_deglupta) tree.
It's now about 1 metre tall, and we've noticed a concerning 'bubbly' texture on most of its upper stems. The "bubbliness" is the same sort of hard-ness as the stems; somewhat smooth, and sort of waxy.

I could easily scrape/cut the "wax" away, in which case it initially maintained it's shape and texture. It was relatively easy to 'smush' between my fingers, at which point it felt somewhat wet and 'mushy', and had no discernable "contents".

The mid-height stems seem less affected, and the lowest seem entirely unaffected.
The leaves in the crown also seem more curled than I would have expected.

- We're in North London, UK.
- The tree was bought in the summer.
- The tree was outside on a South-facing Patio through to mid-October, well before it got properly cold.
- It was then moved to a (not-really sealed or insulated) South-facing lean-to/greenhouse, which stayed above 10 C until mid-November.
- We brought it fully inside the night before the first frost.

Images below. (click for hi-res images)

---

**Qustion: Is our tree OK?**

If not, is it save-able?

---

**Affected Branches:**

[image: Heavily Affected branch]
[image: Heavily Affected branch]
[image: Lightly Affected branch]

**Unaffected branch**

[image: Unaffected branch]

**Overall tree**

[image: Overall tree]

**Results of scraping wax**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It does not look okay - not sure what all the soggy white stuff is on the stems, or at least it looks soggy - have you tried scraping some off then inspecting with a magnifying glass to see if there are any creatures or eggs or something inside?

Comment: Can't see in photo but it could be scale insects.

Comment: @blacksmith37 at first glance,yes, but  the high resolution pictures show the deposits as being shiny, soggy or wet, not dry and fluffy... doesn't mean it isn't scale, but that's not typically how scale looks

Comment: @Bamboo, @blacksmith37; more detail added.

Comment: I could magnify the two last pictures. If I'm right, this is not one lump of some waxy material. You may have scales stacked atop each other. See if you can separate them into individual "disks". At-least that's what it seems to be from the picture.

Comment: I;m wondering about a psyllid infestation such as Eucalyptus sucker, but you'd usually see something under the leaves as well - check the backs of all leaves. And have  you noticed any stickiness anywhere, on the leaves or stems?

Comment: Nothing at all unexpected anywhere else and no stickiness. I have noticed that if I scrape some of the 'waxy' stuff off and crush it between my fingers, it smells quite distinctly of eucalyptus.

Comment: We contacted the vendor and they believe that this is Oedema brought on by high-humidity (presumably from being brought inside, and perhaps by over-watering?). Does that seem like a plausible answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We contacted the vendor and they believe that this is Oedema brought on by high-humidity (presumably from being brought inside, and perhaps by over-watering?)

We moved it to a less humid location and reduced the watering somewhat, the waxy surface gradually receded, and didn't return the next year. Success!